# Mac Notes Keeps Opening Up every 5 seconds

Tags: notes.app

Yesterday, I decided to set up iMessage on my Macbook Pro.  And ever since then, Mac Notes keeps opening up every 5 seconds.  I close it, or force quit, and it opens again in 5 seconds.  But even when it's idle Mac Notes is restarting every 5 seconds, and assumes priority on my screen, so I am battling to type and work on my Mac.  It's as though it wants to create a new note each time.

Macbook Pro
Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.3

Comment: Have you disabled iCloud Notes in System Prefs -> iCloud -> Notes?

Comment: Thanks bassplayer. I have disabled Notes in iCloud, and all mail accounts, but it's still doing it's thing.  I have done a PRAM reset, and tried to delete the Notes PList, but still the same.  My next attempt will be to reload OSX.

Comment: OK. I didn't think that would fix it but it was the next thing to try. If you didn't want to just face-in reload it, you could schedule a Genius appointment and see if they have any thoughts. Who knows, perhaps there is a .plist somewhere that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you previously had Twonky Media Server installed and removed it, that could be the culprit. I had the same issue, though with Lotus Notes (also conveniently called Notes.app), starting/popping up every 5 seconds.

`CleanTwonkyServerData.command` (in `/Users/Shared`) was the culprit, it might be the same for you.

Comment: removing cleangtwonkyserverdata solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance it's useful, I'll share my experience with Reminders, which did something similar to me. It wouldn't quit, and I couldn't even shut down the machine because it would pop right back up again. I finally tracked down the problem -- I had GeekTool displaying Reminders on the desktop. The script kept reopening the app to check in at its specified interval, I guess.

Rather a long shot that that's your problem here, I realize, but just in case it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Search twonky "on this mac" you will see a file named cleantwonkyserver or something to that effect.. Trash it!!! Notes will stop popping up!

Comment: What is this file actually doing?